# Linear Regression Error in feature matrix step

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, matrix

I'm trying to code the design function used in linear regression using numpy and I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-
>   packages\nose\case.py", line 197, in runTest
>      self.test(*self.arg)
>   File "C:\Users\visha\machinelearning\test.py", line 23, in test_compute_Phi
>    assert type(Phi) == np.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix
>   AssertionError

input > x: input vector of shape n x 1,
         p: the number of polynomials/features

TEST CASE :   x = np.mat('1.;2.;3') , P=2

can you please help me correct this code ?

**code**

```
def compute_Phi(x,p):

    x = np.asarray(x)
    Phi = np.zeros(shape=(len(x),p+1))
    for i in range(0,p+1):
        Phi[:,i] = np.power(x,i).reshape(x.shape[0],)

    return Phi
```

Comment: It is working for me. Don't know why it's causing you an error. Try explicitly converting Phi to a matrix in your return statement as `np.matrix(Phi)`

Comment: Hi @bkshi, I did and it throws a ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1,3) into shape (3,1)